# iPhone Developer Program registration for UK trading partnership

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program, app-store

I have been looking into this for a long time and have found no definitive answer. I can't be the only person to have faced this problem and am wondering how you guys proceeded in similar cases.

I'm part of a partnership, based in the UK, trading as, lets say, "ABCD iPhone Apps" (legally, a perfectly legitimate way of doing business). I've now developed an iPhone App and I want our company name ("ABCD iPhone Apps") to appear as the seller in the App Store. This way, any future Apps that we develop can all get released under the "ABCD iPhone Apps" aegis too.

Given that we aren't an incorporated company (and probably never will be), is it possible for us to enroll in the iPhone Developer Program as a company? Or is there another solution?

(Note: I do also have an Individual account but that is for personal projects and is in no way connected to the partnership, and shall remain that way)

**EDIT: I've just spoken to a guy at ADC UK and he tells me there is no other solution.**

For a company to be approved on the Developer Program, Apple needs to see a copy of the company's Certificate of Incorporation during the registration process, otherwise no approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just been thinking the very same thing...

Response from Apple:

> Thank you for contacting the Apple Developer Connection.
>
> Please know we do not accept a DBA or
>   a document pertaining to a trade name.
>   If we requested business documents we
>   would require you to fax in a
>   certificate of incorporation.
>
> We hope this information is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way, I've just gone through the same.